# Could we draw field lines for colour charge?

Tags: field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, confinement, color-charge

Electromagnetic charge can be represented with field lines. These are pleasingly intuitive and can be used to visualise Gauss's Law and Maxwell's Laws. Later on Gauss and Maxwell get rolled into a tensor equations (I'm thinking of the [electromagnetic tensor](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node121.html)) which is used to make electromagnetic terms in the Lagrangian.

In the Lagrangian we also have similar terms for gluons. Could these be worked back to Maxwell-Gauss like equations? Could these then be used to produce field lines for colour charge?

Comment: Lee Smolin has a discussion of this sort of thing at the pop-sci level in Three Roads to Quantum Gravity. He includes the gravitational field.

Comment: @BenCrowell oh thanks, that sounds like its worth a read